# php: split a string in half at white space until none of the resulting parts are longer than x number of words

Tags: php, string, split

How would I split a sentence into half, until none of the resulting parts are longer than, say 8 words?

Here is a sample text of 39 words:

> "This is a long string that can be different since this is a black box
>   function and I do not know what strings I am going to receive, but I
>   need to be shorter for sure by a lot."

Resulting output

```
This is a long string that can be
different since this is a black box
function and I do not know what strings
I am going to receive, but I
need to be shorter for sure by a
lot
```

Any tips please?

Comment: When you say "split a sentence into half" - you mean multiple pieces, not *half*, which means in to two equal pieces.  Or do you mean repetitively splitting in half, until no piece is longer than 8?

Comment: If this a homework/interview question then it should be tagged as such...

Comment: Orbling: Thanks the second one would be it,  repetitively splitting in half, until no piece is longer than 8. James, no I am doing this for my own hobby project.

Comment: He was minutes earlier but he edited the answer and copied same example...Please verify injustice with me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$text = "This is a long string that can be different since this is a black box function and I do not know what strings I am going to receive, but I need to be shorter for sure by a lot.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 40, "\n", true); // assign number as per you requirement

echo "$newtext\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).  Your example lines are about 35 characters long. Here's one that goes to 40.

```
echo wordwrap($long_string, 40);
```

Prints:

```
This is a long string that can be
different since this is a black box
function and I do not know what strings
I am going to receive, but I need to be
shorter for sure by a lot.
```

Specify the 3rd parameter to `wordwrap()` if your linebreaks are `\r\n` rather than the default `\n`.

Comment: +1 A possible problem with `wordwrap()`, is that it works on characters, not words.  The problem is stated in words, though I imagine that might be an issue of the question presentation, could well desire the output `wordwrap()` gives.

Comment: Thanks looks good, I will go with this. I notice Wazzy posted almost the same but a bit sooner, so I will mark that as the answer, but vote up both.

Comment: @giorgio79 I was actually a minute earlier than Wazzy, but accept whichever you like :)

Comment: Sorry, in that case it goes to you. :) Very very elegant solution. I love these little php tricks. Very nice.

Comment: You had posted after me but what stuck me how can we give same example

Comment: [Literally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769116/php-split-a-string-in-half-at-white-space-until-none-of-the-resulting-parts-are/7769919#7769919) -1: Part "I am going to receive, but I need to be" is longer than the said 8 words ;)

Answer (score 2):

Taking your question literally

> How would I split a sentence into half, until none of the resulting parts are longer than, say 8 words?

, more specifically

> repetitively splitting in half, until no piece is longer than 8.

into account:

```
$sentence = "This is a long string that can be different since this is a black box function and I do not know what strings I am going to receive, but I need to be shorter for sure by a lot.";

$say8words = 8;

# start with one piece, use preg_split for finer control.
$pieces[] = explode(' ', $sentence); 

while(is_a_piece_longer_than($pieces, $say8words))
    $pieces = splitting_in_half($pieces);

echo as_string($pieces);
```

Which will give you:

```
This is a long string that
can be different since this
is a black box function
and I do not
know what strings I am going
to receive, but I
need to be shorter for
sure by a lot.
```

and might not be what you actually thought you were asking for.

Functions:

```
function is_a_piece_longer_than($pieces, $length)
{
    return $length < max(array_map('count', $pieces));
}

function splitting_in_half($pieces)
{
    $halfs = array();
    foreach($pieces as $full)
    {
        $count = count($full);
        $halfCount = 1 + (int) ($count / 2);
        foreach(array_chunk($full, $halfCount) as $half)
            $halfs[] = $half;
    }
    return $halfs;
}

function as_string($pieces)
{
    return array_reduce($pieces, function($v, $w) { return $v . (strlen($v) ? "\n" : '') . implode(' ', $w);}, '');
}
```

Comment: Very elegant! It is indeed an exact answer. Can I accept multiple answers as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split()`. Check the [documentation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: `str_split()` doesn't safeguard word boundaries.